# Facebook PHP SDK4 - FQL Request

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

somehow my FQL request won't work in PHP. In the Graph API Exporer the Query works fine. This is my main code:

```
$params = array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => "SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid = me()",
);

// graph api request for user data
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me', $params );
$response = $request->execute();
// get response
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

// print profile data
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

This is Facebooks Error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message 'Unsupported method, fql.query' in /vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php:104 Stack trace: #0 /vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php(268): Facebook\FacebookRequestException::create('{"error":{"mess...', Object(stdClass), 400) #1 /www/htdocs/app/facebook.php(97): Facebook\FacebookRequest->execute() #2 {main} thrown in /vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php on line 104
(Path names changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me', $params );
```

with

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/fql?q=SELECT%20friend_count%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20me()');
```

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/#read

Comment: Awesome, altho there is a little mistake (your last ' is after q= not at the end of the array) it worked perfectly. Thanks!